# How can I tell Windows to overwrite a system file on the next reboot?

Tags: windows, rename

Under some circumstances, Windows has to overwrite important files such as csrss.exe and lsass.exe. Such as when updates affect these files. Or when the files are corrupted and repaired with the SFC tool. How does it accomplish this without ending the processes and triggering a blue screen?

I've tried adding the registry value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations` and giving it this value

```
\??\C:\csrss.exe
\??\C:\Windows\System32\csrss.exe
```

But when I rebooted, the registry value was deleted, but no files were changed.

My goal is to be able to overwrite files these files with my own modified versions without using an external tool like a linux live cd.

Yes, I am aware this is stupid. I'm fully responsible for any damage caused by this. Nonetheless, I still want to know how. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hey can you help with some stuff; https://superuser.com/questions/1795020/windows-modify-system-files-once-reboot-or-shutdown-button-pressed/1795290?noredirect=1#comment2811858_1795290

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what I'm trying to do. I was wanting to modify files the way Windows Update does. After experimenting, I found this.

Make an XML file with this in it.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<PendingTransaction Version="3.1">
    <POQ postAction="reboot">
        <MoveFile source="\??\C:\csrss.exe" destination="\??\C:\Windows\System32\csrss.exe"/>
    </POQ>
</PendingTransaction>
```

Then modify the value `SetupExecute` in the key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager` to contain `C:\Windows\System32\poqexec.exe /displayprogress \??\[PATH TO XML]`

This has Windows process the "Primitive Operations Queue" before booting up.

Comment: I'm trying this on Windows 7 and I can't make it work. Can you mention please what OS did you try this on?

Comment: @Mercalli This was a while ago. I know I found this method by breaking windows update. I did it in a vm and analyzed what files were made when windows update wanted me to reboot. I think it was windows 10